# different ways to pass an entire array by reference in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void call_1(T& in){
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(in));  // 12
}

template <int N>
void call_2(int (&in)[N]){
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(in)); // 12
}

int main(){
  int a[] = {1,2,3};
  call_1(a);
  call_2(a); 
  return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions based on the code snippet above:

1- is `call_1` and `call_2` both valid ways to pass an entire array by reference?

2- why is `T&` necessary to have in `call_1`. If `&` is omitted it passes a pointer to
the first element of array. Why doesn't `T&` pass a reference to the first element of the array and instead it references the entire array?

3- Why can't I write `template <T N>` in `call_2` an avoid hard coding `int`? is this
not a valid syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, both are valid.

2. The type of `a` is `int[3]`. But arrays in most rvalue contexts, such as when passing by-value, decay to a pointer. The decaying doesn't happen when passing by-reference, so you end up with `int(&)[3]`.

3. Of course you can, but the type of the array *dimension* is not T, but `size_t`.

So it should be like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void call_2(T (&in)[N]){
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(in)); // 12
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1- is call_1 and call_2 both valid ways to pass an entire array by reference?

Yes. 1 also accepts non-array arguments.

> 2- why is T& necessary to have in call_1

Because without T& you won't have a type for the parameter.

> Why doesn't T& pass a reference to the first element of the array and instead it references the entire array?

That's just not how the language works. When a reference is deduced from an array argument, it is deduced to be a reference to an array.

> 3- Why can't I write `template <T N>` in call_2 an avoid hard coding int? is this not a valid syntax?

Because you haven't told to the compiler what `T` is. There's technically no need to hard code the type of the length of the array. You can make it a template parameter like this:

```
template <class T, T N>
```

But typically hard-conding it isn't a problem. Note that conventionally, std::size_t is used rather than int.

---

> ```
> printf("%d\n", sizeof(in));
> ```

%d is not the correct format specifier for `std::size_t`, so the behaviour of the program is undefined. I recommend using iostreams instead. It's much easier to avoid undefined behaviour with iostreams.

Comment: Thanks, for (2) i'm only referring to removing the '&' sign.

Comment: I did, `If & is omitted it passes a pointer ...`.

Comment: @Dan That statement following the question is correct. You don't have a question regarding removal of &.

Comment: `template <class T, T N>` should probably be `template <class T, std::size_t N>`, so we can pass C-array of `float`/`std::string`/... :)